# Pimcore "Import Definition" how to relocate object to relevant folder

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I have use “**Import Definition**” bundle to import csv and to create data-objects. (https://github.com/w-vision/ImportDefinitions)

Now I need to put imported data-Object to relevant folders. I need to do it automatically.

eg -

1. Import first row of the CSV
2. Check the CSV first row "Category" column value
3. According to column value need to move into relevant folder.

Setting object path "`/products/%Text(mycolumn1);/%Text(mycolumn2);`" is not solution to my requirement.

My csv it’s comes with category code not full name. 
I need to do some mapping.

eg:-
csv column category value is - **OFH**
my data-object folder name is **Office & Furniture Hardware**

I need to match those two and place into correct folder.

What is the best way to do this with “**Import Definitions**”?

if best way is "**interpreter**" please let me know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no much document about Pimcore but I have solve my issue using custom Interpreter.
Here is my solution -

Fist install Import Definition -

https://github.com/w-vision/ImportDefinitions

(it'll install into - `/var/www/html/example2.loc/vendor/w-vision/import-definitions/src/ImportDefinitionsBundle/`)

```
composer require w-vision/import-definitions:^2.0-dev

bin/console pimcore:bundle:enable ImportDefinitionsBundle

bin/console pimcore:bundle:install ImportDefinitionsBundle
```

**Add new custom Interpreter**

Add "**[categorymap.js](https://github.com/TharangaSri/Pimcore-Custom-Interpreter/blob/master/categorymap.js)**" to 
*/var/www/html/example2.loc/vendor/w-vision/import-definitions/src/ImportDefinitionsBundle/Resources/public/pimcore/js/interpreters/categorymap.js*

Add "**[CategoryMap.php](https://github.com/TharangaSri/Pimcore-Custom-Interpreter/blob/master/CategoryMap.php)**" to 
*/var/www/html/example2.loc/vendor/w-vision/import-definitions/src/ImportDefinitionsBundle/Interpreter/CategoryMap.php*

Add "**[CategoryMapInterpreterType.php](https://github.com/TharangaSri/Pimcore-Custom-Interpreter/blob/master/CategoryMapInterpreterType.php)**" to 
*/var/www/html/example2.loc/vendor/w-vision/import-definitions/src/ImportDefinitionsBundle/Form/Type/Interpreter/CategoryMapInterpreterType.php*

Update **[Service.yml](https://github.com/TharangaSri/Pimcore-Custom-Interpreter/blob/master/services.yml)** in -
 */var/www/html/example2.loc/vendor/w-vision/import-definitions/src/ImportDefinitionsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml*

adding Following -

import_definition.interpreter.category_map:
    class: ImportDefinitionsBundle\Interpreter\CategoryMap
    tags:
        - { name: import_definition.interpreter, type: category_map, form-type: ImportDefinitionsBundle\Form\Type\Interpreter\CategoryMapInterpreterType }

Update **[config.yml](https://github.com/TharangaSri/Pimcore-Custom-Interpreter/blob/master/config.yml)** in -

adding follwing -

```
interpreter_categorymap: '/bundles/importdefinitions/pimcore/js/interpreters/categorymap.js'
```

To csv upload run following CLI command -

```
bin/console import-definitions:import -d 1 -p "{\"file\":\"sap_export1.csv\"}"
```

Comment: Pincore guys not recommend to update vendor folder coding.. it's true, then I have move my coding to new bundle. just you have to create new bundle and move this coding to that bundle it'll work without any issue.